# Jersey 2 - return Client's Response from resource method

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I built a reverse proxy (P) to an upstream server (U). A client application (C) will issue a request to P, which will in turn issue a request to U, and the result returned by U should be returned to the client C by proxy P.

When I write the code in P like this (I want the proxy to be as generic as possible, and support multiple result types):

```
Client client = // get the client
Invocation.Builder builder = // configure the call to U
return builder.get(InputStream.class);
```

it works for both JSON and binary data, the result is returned, but the `Content-Type` header is always set to `application/octet-stream`, which is wrong. I could check the result from U for the type and set it to in the response from my proxy P, but then I would have to mess around with error handling etc. whereas when I just return the InputStream and an error occurs, the `builder.get()` method throws an exception which is then propagated to the client.

I would actually like to just take the Response returned by U and use it as the return value of P, like this:

```
Client client = // get the client
Invocation.Builder builder = // configure the call to U
return builder.get(); // returns Response
```

the client C, in my case a Python 3 `requests` application, get the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

I tried the following code:

```
Response upstreamResponse = client./* code code */.get();
upstreamResponse.bufferEntity();
return Response.fromResponse(upstreamResponse);
```

but, alas, the result is the same.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I would have expected the proxy to pass the content type through (and maybe other things like content-length and status).  So it would look a bit more like:

```
Response upstreamResponse = client./* code code */.get();
upstreamResponse.bufferEntity();
return Response.status(upstreamResponse.status())
               .type(upstreamResponse.getMediaType()
                // and so on
```

Realistically, you may or may not want many of the things from the upstreamResponse header too - what about Cookies for example?

Comment: That's exactly my point - I don't want to do this, I would just like to do 'return updstreamResponse', which has all the things you mention already set, and I wouldn't have to do anything.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get able to get this - a proxy is a bit of a specialized use case.  But I could see a pretty simple method to copy as you want.  You could even do like many proxies and add a header to indicate what IP, for example, the request was forward for.  But overall, I think you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: Just one note - I am not writing a fully-fledged, general purpose proxy; I'm writing a small utility for my very specialized use case. But, I still don't know why I can't just return whatever comes from the upstream resource, there must be something there, like a header or sth, which breaks the stream.